# How to increase Tomcat Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have tried increasing tomcat threads using parameter maxThreads="300" as tomcat getting hung.

When I view the tomcat threads displayed in windows resource monitor CPU tab, 100-110 threads number is being displayed against tomcat process.

Please let me if this is correct way to view the number of threads as the increased number is not displaying in the resource monitor tab.

Comment: If you have exhausted the processing capacity of your system, increasing the number of threads will make things worse, not better.

Comment: Do you specify `maxThreads=300` on a Connector, on an Executor or on both? Is an explicit Executor used at all? It would make sense to  show a bit more of your configuration and also tell us which version of Tomcat you are using.

Comment: @JimGarrison Processing capacity of the system is more than enough, the only problem we are facing is the tomcat doesn't respond any more to the requests. The page keeps on loading, rotates. we are unable to find any errors in the tomcat logs, system logs. The only parameter that is found suspicious is the thread shown in the resource monitor for the tomcat process is 100+ to 110, whenever this is happening

Comment: @MarkusBenko we have specified on a connector on both port 8080 and 8009, tomcat version is 7

Comment: @MarkusBenko some parts server.xml configuration  pasted below           <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="300" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="300"/>
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>

Comment: @praveenkolluri Ok, so you will have two separate implicit Executors, one for HTTP and one for AJP. When specifying maxThreads *up to that* number of threads will be spawned depending on actual load. If you don't get more than 100 concurrently processed requests Tomcat won't start more than 100 threads no matter what is configured for maxThreads. That probably also means that the real cause for your problem is not too few executor threads.

Comment: @MarkusBenko I don't see any other potential issues that is causing the application to hung. RAM for the server is configured to 16 GB and out of that 8 GB is allocated to tomcat. The same code being executed in 4 other servers without any problem. Have checked DB level locks and query executions, no problem with DB.

Comment: @praveenkolluri Either way, the maxThreads setting should have an effect, but as said before threads are only started on demand despite a few ones which are kept alive even when idle. If the setting doesn't solve your problem I'd suggest tracking it down using thread dumps and head dumps. Sounds like something must be different from the other 4 instances.